# Datatables server side data response error

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am getting the following error when I try to fetch data from server side script

> DataTables warning: table id=example - Requested unknown parameter '0'
>   for row 0. For more information about this error, please see
>   http://datatables.net/tn/4

What am I doing wrong ?

Here's the HTML

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#example').DataTable({
        serverSide: true,
        "columnDefs": [
            { "title": "Sr.",           "name": "sr",           "width": "5%",  "targets": 0 },
            { "title": "ECode",         "name": "code",         "width": "5%",  "targets": 1 },
            { "title": "Employee Name", "name": "name",         "width": "25%", "targets": 2 },
            { "title": "Guardian",      "name": "guardian",     "width": "20%", "targets": 3 },
            { "title": "DOA",           "name": "doa",          "width": "10%", "targets": 4 },
            { "title": "Department",    "name": "department",   "width": "20%", "targets": 5 },
            { "title": "Designation",   "name": "designation",  "width": "20%", "targets": 6 }
        ],
        ajax: {
            url: 'employees/listdata/all',
            type: 'POST'
        }
    });
});
</script>
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
</table>
```

Here's the JSON response

```
{
"recordsTotal":842,
"recordsFiltered":842,
"data":[
    {"DT_RowId":"28","sr":"1","code":"28","name":"ABHISHEK SHARMA","guardian":"RAMESH CHAND","doa":"10\/12\/2013","department":"Welding Shop","designation":"M. OPERATOR - NUT FORMER"},
    {"DT_RowId":"66","sr":"2","code":"66","name":"ACHHAY LAL","guardian":"BAHARAN MAHTO","doa":"26\/06\/2013","department":"Workshop","designation":"STORE KEEPER"},
    {"DT_RowId":"454","sr":"3","code":"454","name":"ACHHAY LAL","guardian":"JAI KUMAR","doa":"26\/01\/2015","department":"Cutting Department","designation":"QUALITY CONTROLLER"}
    ]
}
```

Comment: because of the differnce between the number of columns in the `json` and `datatable` column

Comment: Columns are exactly same 7 is table definition and 7 in JSON response, DT_RowId is an optional parameter which sets the ID property of the tr node to this value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution and it was as usual very simple but overlooked

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#example').DataTable({
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "columnDefs": [
            { "data": "sr",             "title": "Sr.",             "name": "sr",           "width": "5%",  "targets": 0 },
            { "data": "code",           "title": "ECode",           "name": "code",         "width": "5%",  "targets": 1 },
            { "data": "name",           "title": "Employee Name",   "name": "name",         "width": "25%", "targets": 2 },
            { "data": "guardian",       "title": "Guardian",        "name": "guardian",     "width": "15%", "targets": 3 },
            { "data": "doa",            "title": "DOA",             "name": "doa",          "width": "10%", "targets": 4 },
            { "data": "department",     "title": "Department",      "name": "department",   "width": "20%", "targets": 5 },
            { "data": "designation",    "title": "Designation",     "name": "designation",  "width": "20%", "targets": 6 }
        ],
        ajax: {
            url: 'employees/listdata/all',
            type: 'POST'
        }
    });
});
</script>
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%"></table>
```

I added the data property to each column and it worked perfectly.